# Cannot create Repo with Databricks CLI

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am using `Azure DevOps` and `Databricks`. I created a simplified CI/CD Pipeline which triggers the following `Python` script:

```
existing_cluster_id = 'XXX'

notebook_path = './'
repo_path = '/Repos/abc@def.at/DevOpsProject'
git_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/XXX/DDD/'



import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

from databricks_cli.configure.config import _get_api_client
from databricks_cli.configure.provider import EnvironmentVariableConfigProvider
from databricks_cli.sdk import JobsService, ReposService

config = EnvironmentVariableConfigProvider().get_config()
api_client = _get_api_client(config, command_name="cicdtemplates-")
repos_service = ReposService(api_client)

 
repo = repos_service.create_repo(url=git_url, provider="azureDevOpsServices", path=repo_path+"_new")
```

When I run the pipeline I always get an error (from the last line):

```
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5318746Z     raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError(message, response=e.response)
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5320017Z requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://adb-XXX.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/repos
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5321095Z  Response from server: 
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5321811Z  { 'error_code': 'BAD_REQUEST',
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5322485Z   'message': 'Remote repo not found. Please ensure that:\n'
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5323156Z              '1. Your remote Git repo URL is valid.\n'
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5323853Z              '2. Your personal access token or app password has the correct '
2022-12-07T23:09:23.5324513Z              'repo access.'}
```

In `Databricks`, I connect my repo with Azure DevOps: In Git I created a full access token which I added to Databricks' Git Integration and I am able to pull and push in `Databricks`.

For my CI/CD pipeline, I created variables containing my `Databricks` Host address and my token. When I change the token, I get a  different error message (403 http code) - so the token seems to be fine.

Here a screenshot of my variables.

[image]

I have really no clue what I am doing wrong. I tried to run a simplified version of the official Databricks code [here](https://github.com/mshtelma/databricks_ml_demo).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error with the databricks CLI. I found out that simply `_git` was missing in the git repo url